# Why is it that "racist towards" and "racist against" have the same meaning?

Tags: antonyms

"He is racist **towards** black people."

"He is racist **against** black people."

"Towards" and "against" are antonyms, so why do they mean the same thing here?

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. [Ngrams on these usages](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racist+towards%2C+racist+against&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1770&year_end=1993&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cracist%20towards%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cracist%20against%3B%2Cc0) do not show many hits. I think "prejudiced" towards or against would be more common.

Comment: It's no different with [prejudiced **against**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prejudiced+against%22) / [prejudiced **toward**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prejudiced+toward%22) ([prejudiced **towards**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22prejudiced+towards%22) for *British* bigots).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Weird; I don't think I would use "prejudiced toward(s)" because it's not immediately obvious to me that it couldn't mean the same thing as "prejudiced in favor of". It does sometimes seem to be used that way: see https://books.google.com/books?id=05rWaT-JJ6YC&pg=PA93&dq=%22I'm+prejudiced+toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCjouK0YbUAhVs1oMKHZOtBFEQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22I'm%20prejudiced%20toward%22&f=false

Comment: Not racist against. That's for sure.***to be against someone, yes*** but not ***to be racist against*** someone. To be racist towards someone. (I am not British and I use towards with an s). [towards and against are synonyms, not 100%%]

Comment: @Lambie: Google Books claims 691 written instances of [*racist against blacks*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22racist+against+blacks%22), plus there are many thousands of instances of [***racism** against blacks*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22racism+against+blacks%22) and *...against **black** [people]*. But this in no way implies ***towards/against*** are remotely synonymous - it's just that such metaphoric direction/orientation indicators don't naturally map onto things like ***hostile*** actions/appearances, so people make different choices.

Comment: @FumbleFIngers There are many  things "in books". That doesn't make it good writing. Also, one thing is to find something in a novel or script. Another is to use an expression that sounds best. None of these search devices can discriminate. They just pile everything into the pot.

Comment: @Lambie: I think you make too much of your own stylistic preferences. Have a look at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=racism+against+blacks%2Cracism+toward+blacks%2Cracism+towards+blacks&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cracism%20against%20blacks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cracism%20toward%20blacks%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cracism%20towards%20blacks%3B%2Cc0), showing that Americans in particular have no problem with ***racism against blacks*** (linguistically, I mean, not culturally! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers You are diluting my argument. I don't care what books say about style. I care what I say about it. :)

Comment: "Against" and "towards" in this context are not antonyms. There may be senses in which they are, but I can think of others where they are not - e.g. "I throw a ball *against* the wall" and "I throw a ball *towards* the wall". In that example they are near-synonyms.

Comment: @Spencer Yes; Kyle Pearson's answer holds here.

Answer (score 0):

### the meaning of the word "racist" strongly hints at the meaning of the entire phrase

I would say that the adjective *racist* carries the main semantic load in this kind of expression. Any expression of the form "racist [preposition] black people" that is not outright bizarre is likely to receive the same interpretation: for example, "He is racist *to* black people", "He is racist *at* black people", "He is racist *about* black people",  "He is racist *with* black people" all seem like they would convey pretty much the same idea (although they don't all sound equally natural to me).

There are prepositions that couldn't work at all in this context: for example, "He is racist *from* black people" and "He is racist *of* black people" both just sound bizarre. But in general, as long as the meaning of the preposition is approximately right, it won't make a big difference to the meaning of the phrase. People already have an idea of what kind of beliefs a racist is likely to have. So I would say that which preposition a speaker uses after *racist* is likely to be based on convention or analogy, and not on clear semantic criteria.

### In most contexts, 'towards' and 'against' have a similar meaning and are not antonyms

I don't agree that " 'towards' and 'against' are antonyms".

In the physical senses of these words, *against* generally implies contact and *towards* generally implies lack of contact, but they both indicate the same direction (facing something). For example, "I pushed the chair *against* the wall" doesn't mean the opposite of "I pushed the chair *towards* the wall." I would say that the "antonym" of *towards* in most contexts is actually *(away) from.*

It's harder for me to say what the "antonym" of *against* would be; when talking about something like a current, the opposite would seem to be *with* ("swimming against the current" vs. "swimming with the current").

In non-physical senses, it can be hard to distinguish the meaing of *towards* and *against.* For example, ["towards the wind" and "against the wind"](http://www.wgt.com/forums/t/11125.aspx) are as far as I can tell synonymous, probably because there is no way to make physical contact with the wind.

### "Prejudiced against" seems to me more natural than either "racist against" or "racist towards"

I would say that the word *prejudiced* seems more natural than the word *racist* before a prepositional phrase indicating the target of a racist attitude. Specifically, the most natural wording for me is "*prejudiced against* [racial/ethnic group]".

As FumbleFingers pointed out in the comments, some people do use "prejudiced toward(s) [race/ethnic group]" to denote negative, racist attitudes; however, I don't think this wording is as common as "prejudiced against [race/ethnic group]". There is actually a bit of ambiguity, as in non-racial contexts "prejudiced toward(s) X" may indicate a *favorable* attitude toward(s) X (examples: *[Hawai'i Chronicles Two](https://books.google.com/books?id=05rWaT-JJ6YC&pg=PA93&dq=%22I%27m%20prejudiced%20toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCjouK0YbUAhVs1oMKHZOtBFEQ6AEIPTAE#v=onepage&q=%22I%27m%20prejudiced%20toward%22&f=false), [Seth's Personal Canadian Vernacular](https://books.google.com/books?id=ILXTDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT6&dq=%22I%27m%20prejudiced%20toward%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiCjouK0YbUAhVs1oMKHZOtBFEQ6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22I%27m%20prejudiced%20toward%22&f=false)*). (In this *particular* context, I might agree that *towards* and *against* could be considered to be antonyms.)

It's likely that the common pre-existing pattern of "prejudiced against X" influenced the choice of preposition in the expression "racist against X".

The source of the pattern "racist toward(s) X" is not so clear, but it might have been influenced by constructions like "hostile toward(s) [race/ethnic group]" or "attitudes toward(s) [race/ethnic group]".